# NoClassDefFoundException with google_play_services_lib in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

I'm trying to do a simple map app using Android and I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundException`.
I have tried different approaches:
First - I imported the project in eclipse using `Import existing code into workspace`
Second - Create a new project using a existing android code.

Then I try to import the .jar file manually. Didn't work either.
I'm trying this for a couple days now and I can't find a solution.

None of them worked please help.
Here is my stack:

```
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733): Process: com.example.teste, PID: 29733
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at com.example.teste.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:16)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-29 17:27:41.672: E/AndroidRuntime(29733):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Import the google-play-services library into your workspace (looks like you do that in step 1). Right click the project you want to use the library with, click Properties. In the sections column on the left, click Android and in the data window on the right that comes up scroll all the way down (below the Project Build Target section). There is a Library section in the bottom, click add and click your google play library. Hit apply and see if it works.

Comment: Hello zgc7009, I tried that before but I forgot to mention, it was not the problem. I done a lot of things and the last thing I did was download all API levels until API 15 and I target the google-lib for Google API 15 and it worked, I was trying to compile it with Google API 19. It solved the problem, but I´m not sure if it was only that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target it to API level 15.